# Concatenación en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una concatenación en `c#` en donde el resultado quiero que sea igual a lo siguiente:

```
variable = "null,null"
```

Pero esta concatenación la estoy haciendo en un `for` y queda mas o menos así:

```
string variable = "";

for (int pos= 0; pos < asientos.Length; pos++)
{
    if (pos == asientos.Length - 1)
        variable += "null";
    else
        variable += "null" + ",";
}
```

El `if` que coloco en la iteracion es para que al final no se agrege la `,` (coma), ahora la pregunta o mas bien duda es, ¿hay alguna forma mejor de hacer esa validación en esa concatenación?, y si la hay, ¿Cual es?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) y así te evitas crear el ciclo `for` y tienes un código más limpio y sencillo de mantener. Aquí te proveo un ejemplo:

```
using System.Linq;

//...

//asumo que asientos es un arreglo
//para el ejemplo, es de tipo int pero puede ser de cualquier tipo
int[] asientos = { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.Write(
    //String.Join permitirá unir todos los elementos de un arreglo/lista
    String.Join(
        ",", //colocamos cómo queremos que se separen los elementos
        asientos.ToList() //convertimos el arreglo en lista, si ya es una lista no necesitas aplicar este método
            .Select(x => "null") //aplicamos una conversión a los elementos para que sean "null" que es tu requerimiento
        )
    );
```

Comment: Hola Luiggi Mendoza, usando Linq evitas el `for` pero probablemente se pierda rendimiento al recorrer la lista de asientos y el `ConvertAll` estás haciendo una conversión a `string` que se llevará su tiempo. Tu código se podría simplificar con `String.Join(",", asientos.AsEnumerable().Select(x => "null"))` Échale un ojo a [este](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wXZv3C) .NET Fiddle. Saludos

Comment: @rsciriano del sitio en inglés: [String.Join vs. StringBuilder: which is faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/585860/1065197). Primero leí esa respuesta antes de ofrecer la mía. Como se puede ver, la diferencia de rendimiento es tan mínima y para un caso como este, realmente el ahorrar menos de 10 milisegundos es innecesario. A menos claro, que trabajes en un sistema donde cada milisegundo vale como un marcapasos (aunque dudo [pero puedo equivocarme] que utilices C# en ese caso). Por último, está más de moda elegir legibilidad de código sobre rendimiento para casos como este.

Comment: Hola Luiggi, lo del rendimiento del `string.Join` ya lo había leído por algún lado. Y tienes razón, en muchos casos la ganancia en rendimiento no es importante y puede primar más que el código sea más legible y mantenible. Yo uso el `StringBuilder` o el `StringWriter` cuando tengo que componer una cadena compleja, con saltos de línea, tabuladores, espacios,...etc y me he fijado mas en la mantenibilidad del código que en el rendimiento. Donde si se nota es si pretendes construir una cadena muy grande usando `"string1" + "string2"` Saludos

Comment: @rsciriano coincido contigo. Pero para este caso, donde no se sabe cuántos elementos se van a unir, pues esto me parece que está bien en defecto. Apoyo la opción de `StringBuilder` mucho más que la simple concatenación de cadenas (como está en otras respuestas). Es más, la que me parece mucho mejor todavía es la solución "compacta" que ofreces, me parece que tiene mucho mejor rendimiento que la mía.

Comment: Lo que menos me ha gustado de la tuya es el `ConvertAll`, con eso probablemente estés llamando a [`Object.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) que además se suele sobreescribir para personalizar lo que devuelve. Por eso es mejor usar el método [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Hola prodias usar el [remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx), de esta forma eliminarías el último carácter que no necesitas:

```
string variable = "";

for (int pos= 0; pos < asientos.Length; pos++)
{
        variable += "null" + ",";
}

variable = variable.Remove(variable.Length - 1);
```

> **String.Remove(Int32)**
>
> Elimina todos los caracteres, desde un comienzo hasta una posición
>   especificada

Comment: string variable = "";

Comment: @MBahamondes Gracias fue un typo de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Para implementar esto veo dos opciones:

**Opción 1 (clásica)**

```
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

for (int i= 0; i < asientos.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(",");
    }
    sb.Append("null");        
}
var variable = sb.ToString()
```

Las claves de esta implementación son:

- Usar un `System.Text.StringBuilder` para concatenar la cadena porque es mas óptimo que concatenar objetos `string` porque, al ser inmutables, se realiza una re-asignación de memoria en cada concatenación
- Al añadir ","  al principio de cada iteración (excepto para el primer elemento) evita repetir la cadena. Esto es útil sobre todo cuando el valor que estás concatenando cambia en cada iteración

**Opción 2 (compacta)**

```
var variable = string.Join(
    ",", 
    System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat<string>("null", asientos.Length)
);
```

Las claves de esta implementación son:

- Usar `System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat` para crear el array de "null" las veces que sea necesario (se requiere .NET >= 4.0)
- Usar `string.Join` para generar la cadena final

Estos ejemplos se pueden ver funcionando en este [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wm7Bac)

Realmente no sé si la opción 1 podría ofrecer más rendimiendo pero lo que está claro es que la opción 2 es muchísimo más compacta

Answer (score 0):

Esta podría ser una solución:

```
 String variable = "";

            for (int pos = 0; pos < asientos.Length;; pos++)
            {
                variable += "null" + ",";
            }
            variable = variable.Substring(0, variable.Length - 1);
            Console.Write(variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la variable `asientos` corresponde a un `array`, te conviene utilizar el método `Join` de los `String`.

Ejemplo:

```
string[] array = { "ejemplo","ejemplo2","ejemplo3" };
string palabra = String.Join(",", array);
```

Ahora si quieres especificamente el valor `null`, mira que declaras a variable como int y luego le asignas un string, yo lo haría así:

```
string variable = "";
for (int pos = 0; pos < array.Length; pos++)
{
    variable += "null";
    if (pos != array.Length - 1) { variable += ","; }                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edite tu pregunta un poco en la definición de "variable" debe ser tipo `String`.

Creo que puedes usar un `remove()` como comenta @WilfredoP o `substring()`, por ejemplo:

```
String variable = "";
string[] asientos = new string[] { "asiento Sylvia", "asient Doru", "asiento Helen" };
for (int pos= 0; pos < asientos.Length; pos++)
{    
        variable += "null" + ",";
}
variable = variable.Substring(0, variable.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción, que me parece que nadie a mencionado sería:

1) Concatenar todos los elementos del array y una coma (menos el último elemento).

2) Afuera del ciclo concatena el último elemento que quedó (sin coma por supuesto).

El código quedaría así:

```
string variable = "";
for (int pos= 0; pos < asientos.Length - 1; pos++)
{
    variable += "null" + ",";
}
variable += asientos[asientos.Length - 1];
```